# Сравнение даты в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли как-то сравнивать дату в таком виде: `2011-12-27 (гггг-мм-дд)` прямо в запросе, например, вытянуть только те записи, у которых поле с датой от `2011-07-20` до `2011-12-27`? Или только проверкой через цикл всех записей? Подскажите, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE `date_fld` BETWEEN '20.07.2011' AND '27.12.2011'
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Спасибо, работает)))

Comment: Чудеса предпраздничные!))

Answer (score 2):

Дату именно в таком формате, (кстати, `VARCHAR`?) именно при таких условиях можно сравнивать как строку

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date`>'2011-07-20' AND `date`<'2011-12-27'
```

Если это еще можно сделать, я бы все же рекомендовал поставить полю тип `TIMESTAMP` (ну или `INT` и заполнять его `unix_timestamp`'ом)

Comment: Дело в том, что заполняю поле не я, а joomla, компонент virtuemart, там я добавил дополнительное поле "дата отъезда", ну а там всё в одну таблицу, если поставлю тип TIMESTAMP, то уже нельзя будет загонять туда текст. Тип поля char у меня) Спасибо, попробую

Comment: А-а, ну да, там такой шаманизм - обычное дело. В последнем сайте меня vmart достал и от него одна корзина осталась, остальное на com_php))

Comment: Вот-вот-вот) Не обижайся, я галочку поставлю Виталию Кустову, т.к. он первый ответил, ну а пальцы я вам обоим поставил)